# Linked list program with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include "PersonList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

PersonList::PersonList()
{
    head=NULL; //Head is a PersonRec*
}
struct PersonRec
{
    string aName;
    int aBribe;
    PersonRec* link;
};
void PersonList::AddToList()
{

    //string a;
    //int b;
    PersonRec* p;                  
    p=new PersonRec;


    p->link=NULL;
    cout << "\nEnter the person's name: ";
    cin >> p->aName;
    cout<< "\nEnter the person's contribution: ";
    cin >> p->aBribe;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<1<<endl;
        head=p;
    }
    else if(head!=NULL)     //The problem is in here.
    {
        PersonRec *currPtr=head;
        bool x=true;
        while(x==true)
        {
            currPtr=currPtr->link;    
            if(currPtr==NULL)
            {
                currPtr=p;
                x=false;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is a program that is supposed to input a name and a bribe into a linked list through dynamic memory allocation, and output the result upon request (I have only placed the input function here because it is the only one with problems). The first element inputs and outputs fine, but if I try to input a second one it is not output. The program compiles, but since adding a node is different for all nodes after the first, the problem must be with the portion I have commented as the problem. Any help would be appreciated. This is homework, yes, so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code you use for outputting the contents of the list. What made you think that the problem isn't there?

Comment: The problem was there because I just fixed it, sorry for not posting this sooner.

Comment: For adding to the list, you need to set `tail->link = newElement`, right? But you don't seem to do that anywhere then how is it added to the list?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your homework, I'm not going to give you the code, but rather lead you to the solution :)

The problem is that you set your local variable `currPtr` to point to the newly added element instead of setting the `link` of the last record to point to it.

I believe the following may have confused you:

```
a = 7;
b = a;
b = 6;
```

Here, the value of `a` did not change, regardless of the fact that we copied its **value** into `b` in the second statement.

Analogously, in the following sequence of statements

```
currPtr = currPtr->link;
currPtr = p;
```

the value of currPtr->link did not change regardless of the fact that currPtr and link are pointers, because you're changing their **values**, not the fields they're pointing to.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I found the solution!

Comment: If this was the solution, you could accept it. If it wasn't, just disregard it :)